# How to select all rows which have a distinct phone numbers from sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, distinct

In my database there are 3 columns:

- id
- name
- number.

More than one row can have the same phone number. I want to select all rows which has distinct phone numbers. There should be only one row with one phone number. Other rows should not have the same phone number.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the table schema and what you've tried so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I think this question is very clear so that anyone can understand.

Comment: seems like you are looking for some sort of grouping, unfortunately there are too little details to help you there, what exactly do you want to have happened to the rows you do not want to show?

Comment: @ifran however it shows very little effort on your part - the first header of the link I showed you was "Search, and research"

Comment: @laith now i have edited my question and included more details.can you please help?

Comment: @irfan the way you are phrasing it is confusing, from your last comments/edits I would guess you indeed want to have all rows that have `UNIQUE` phone numbers that do not appear in any other row. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use GROUP BY clause, something like this:

```
SELECT PhoneNumber FROM YourTable GROUP BY PhoneNumber
```

Comment: pretty sure this is not what OP wants, since he said he wants `all rows which has distinct phone numbers` not only `all distinct phone numbers`

Comment: all rows which has distinct phone number.

Comment: Do you want to have all rows where number appears only once? What in case rows have the same phone number? Is name the same for those as well or not?